# How to split the list of values in a sublist based on the first number in a element?

Tags: python-3.x, list, split

I have a list which looks like:

```
lines = 
['1 22698U 93041A   08176.51164820  .00000248  00000-', 
'2 22698 089.5192 046.4765 0091800 046.2114 314.6604', 
'1 22698U 93041A   08176.93361871 +.00000248 +00000121', 
'2 22698 089.5191 046.4531 0091744 044.8831 315.9716',
'1 22698U 93041A   08177.84788861  .00000094  00000-',
'2 22698 089.5188 046.4030 0091715 041.9519 318.8655']
```

I would like to split `lines`  into 3 sublists like:

```
sublist_1 =
 ['1 22698U 93041A   08176.51164820  .00000248  00000-', 
 '2 22698 089.5192 046.4765 0091800 046.2114 314.6604']
 sublist_2 = 
 ['1 22698U 93041A   08176.93361871 +.00000248 +00000121', 
'2 22698 089.5191 046.4531 0091744 044.8831 315.9716',]
 sublist_3 =
 ['1 22698U 93041A   08177.84788861  .00000094  00000-',
'2 22698 089.5188 046.4030 0091715 041.9519 318.8655']
```

The splitting should be based on the first number of a value in a list. Like sublist should contain one value from a sequence that starts with '1' and another that starts with '2'

I will appreciate any suggestions on how can I manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy.reshape()

```
import numpy as np
lines = np.array(lines)
lines = lines.reshape(-1, 2)
```

lines[0], lines[1] and lines[2] are your sublists respectively.

```
sublist_1, sublist_2, sublist_3 = lines
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by list comprehension, enumerate and list slicing like

```
lines =['1 22698U 93041A   08176.51164820  .00000248  00000-',
'2 22698 089.5192 046.4765 0091800 046.2114 314.6604',
'1 22698U 93041A   08176.93361871 +.00000248 +00000121',
'2 22698 089.5191 046.4531 0091744 044.8831 315.9716',
'1 22698U 93041A   08177.84788861  .00000094  00000-',
'2 22698 089.5188 046.4030 0091715 041.9519 318.8655']

sublist_1, sublist_2, sublist_3 = [[v, lines[i*2+1]] for i, v in enumerate(lines[::2])]
```

OR with zip

```
sublist_1, sublist_2, sublist_3 = (list(v) for v in zip(lines[::2], lines[1::2]))
```